# How to throw compilation error when a json key is missing at the time of method call in iava

Tags: java

I am passing json as an method argument. This json object has certain keys to be present and I want to throw compilation error when the key is missing at the time of calling the method. Can someone tell is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be a runtime error. You cannot check for such a thing at compilation time

Comment: You can't 'throw' compilation errors at all, and you can't *print* them 'at the time of the method call' because it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

As @Phil has mentioned, it would be a runtime error. My answer here is to how to capture that. As per my understanding you can use `jackson ObjectMapper` to help you. For this

1. Include dependency of jackson mapper in your project
2. Create a model class and mark your keys as **required**.
3. In method use `try-catch` to handle the `ClassCastException` or `RuntimeException` to validate your input json.